# Change MVC validation usage

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a second code in my cshtml page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="login">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, SignIn_cshtml.SignInWasUnsuccessful)
        <p>Login to menu</p>
        <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { id="input_name", placeholder="User Name" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </div>             
        &nbsp;
        <div>
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { id="input_pwd", placeholder="Password" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </div>              
        <div>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Enable)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Enable)
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="image" src="~/Content/images/LoginButton.png" value="@SignIn_cshtml.SignIn"/>
        </div>
    </div>
}
@section scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#UserName").focus();     
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {

        function add() {
            if ($(this).val() === '') {
                $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('placeholder');
            }
        }

        function remove() {
            if ($(this).val() === $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
                $(this).val('').removeClass('placeholder');
            }
        }

        if (!('placeholder' in $('<input>')[0])) {

            $('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').blur(add).focus(remove).each(add);

            $('form').submit(function () {
                $(this).find('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').each(remove);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
}
```

All works fine. If User name or password are incorrect, I am getting messages under their textbox.

The problem is that now I need change it. Instead of validation messages for User name or password, I need to change their text colour to red (until new focus on textbox I guess). Also Validation summary should be moved to the bottom, outside login div (in its own) and should appear with some style. Sounds not so hard (with javascript), BUT the thing is that I can't change validation. All validation messages should exist.

As I understand, I should somehow run javascript which will show div with validation summary and until new focus, should recolour textbox values from black to red, but how can I run this script? I mean, in the moment when something wrong with user name or password are happened?

P.S Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping I'm understand what you're trying to do correctly but you don't need any custom validation scripts. Include built-in client-side javascript in your scripts section with:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Mark up your model class with DataAnnotations attributes, e.g.:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class LoginModel {
    [DataType(DataType.Text, ErrorMessage="Invalid entry."), 
    MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage="Username must be 100 characters or less."),
    Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false, ErrorMessage="UserName is required.")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

As for your validation summary, you can move it anywhere you want. To add some look and feel just use the overload:

```
@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please fix the following errors:", new { @class = "alert alert-danger"})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a textbox has a validation error, it will have the CSS class `input-validation-error` added to it. So if you want to make the text in the textbox red, just find that (it will be in Site.css in a default MVC project) and change it to:

```
input.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #b94a48;
    color:#FF0000;
}
```

When this is corrected, the class will be removed automatically and change the text back to black.

To move the validation summary outside the login div, just move the `@Html.ValidationSummary()`. You can style it by changing the css for `.validation-summary-errors` (also in Site.css).

Comment: Interesting idea... but about .input-validation-error. I cant change it because of another pages where it is used. My own .input-validation-error are overwrites by Site.css. Is there a way to first of all take styles from layout page? Also, the question about div visibility is still there.

Comment: @OlegsJasjko check my answer for adding your own class to override the input-validation-error styles